# Debug nest.js app in docker container remotely via ssh in vscode

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, vscode-debugger

everyone! I need to debug docker container with nest.js app, but this container running in AWS EC2 instance. Maybe you know how can I do this via ssh localy in vscode?
I have set `node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 main.js` in nest.js container
and I also have opened 9229 port in EC2.

Here is my `launch.json` config

```
    {
      "address": "<public-ip-of-my-ec2-instance>",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "name": "Attach to Remote",
      "port": 9229,
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node"
    }
```